# Is it possible to deduce the value type of a range from the range argument?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-deduction, std-ranges

If you look at standard algorithms like [`std::ranges::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fill) and [`std::ranges::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/generate), they both seem to use additional parameters to deduce the range value type for their output ranges. E.g. `ranges::fill(v, 10)` is able to deduce the value type `T` because of its second argument.

However, when you try to define a similar function but take the second argument away, C++ is no longer able to deduce the value type. For instance, consider the following function:

```
template<typename T, std::output_range<const T&> R>
void ones(R && r)
{
    for (T & value : r) {
        value = 1;
    }
}
```

The code will not compile if you try to call it without explicitly specifying the value type:

```
std::array<int, 3> a;
// ones(a);   // does not compile
ones<int>(a); // redundant!
```

When I try to compile the commented-out code, I get the following error:

```
/home/josiest/sandbox/cpp/template-template-range/sketch.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/josiest/sandbox/cpp/template-template-range/sketch.cpp:19:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘ones(std::array<int, 3>&)’
   19 |     ones(a);
      |     ~~~~^~~
/home/josiest/sandbox/cpp/template-template-range/sketch.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class R>  requires  output_range<R, T> void ones(R&&)’
    9 | void ones(R && r)
      |      ^~~~
/home/josiest/sandbox/cpp/template-template-range/sketch.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/josiest/sandbox/cpp/template-template-range/sketch.cpp:19:9: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’
   19 |     ones(a);
      |     ~~~~^~~
```

Is there some way to deduce the range value type that I'm missing, or is it just not possible?

Comment: Just remove the template parameter, and replace `T &` with `auto &`? Or perhaps `auto &&`.

Comment: Else, you still have `std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(r))>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But what if I want to constrain T? Like `template<std::integral T, ...`

Comment: @Jarod42, I'm a little confused about where that would fit in - isn't it also the same as `ranges::range_value_t`?

Comment: Seems like `T` is fully determined by `r`, is it not?

Comment: @Quimby it seems like it should be!! But alas my compiler tells me otherwise! (I'm using gcc 12.2)

Comment: @JosieThompson Sorry, I did not mean "deduced" but that I agree with `auto&&`. Or is there more possible `T` values for any given `r`? If you want to restrict the calls more, then restrict `r` more? Perhaps using concepts?

Comment: Then perhaps `template <typename T> requires std::output_range<T, std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>`? Or some variation of this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't know how I didn't think of this! This should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
template <typename T> requires std::output_range<T, std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>
```

Or, perhaps:

```
template <typename T> requires std::output_range<T, const std::ranges::range_value_t<T> &>
```

The former expects the element to be moved, and latter expects it to be copied. If you want to support both, you can use both constraints.